# Remove characters after last occurrence of the character of a JSON key value

Tags: ansible, yaml, json-query

I am trying to automate the deployment and invoke lambda function using ansible playbook.To get the arn of the lambda function,I wrote a json query. But here, I need only arn(arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:1234567890:function:dev-Hello-World) but the Ansible script generates arn with version number (arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:1234567890:function:dev-Hello-World:50). I used set_fact and json query to get the arn. But, I want to remove the version number and colon at the end.

I tried to use regex and replace to remove the strings. I am new to JSON and programming.

```
- name: Get the Hello-world arn
  set_fact:
    populate_arn: "{{ Hello-World | json_query('results[0].configuration.function_arn')}}"

- debug:
    var: populate_arn
```

Expected result:arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:1234567890:function:dev-Hello-World

Actual result: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:1234567890:function:dev-Hello-World:50

Answer (score 1):

Foremost, as one can see from [the Lambda API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetFunction.html#API_GetFunction_RequestSyntax), that ARN is the correct, stable, identifier for the function. If you remove the `:50` qualifier, you will get whatever is the `:$LATEST` which can absolutely produce erroneous results

That said, the output from `json_query` is just a string, so you can continue your jinja2 pipeline with (as you mentioned) `regex_replace` to strip the qualifier:

```
- set_fact:
    populate_arn: "{{ Hello-World | json_query('results[0].configuration.function_arn') | regex_replace(':[^:]+$', '') }}"
```

Comment: The only reason i am removing the version is, I am using this arn to attach it to a cloudwatch event. When i do that the cloudwatch event gets attached the versioned arn instead of latest. So when ever i run a new version of my lambda code, i see multiple entries of lambda targets in the cloudwatch event.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, can you explain me the chars you used in the regex?

Comment: the `:` is the literal character, the `[^]` syntax means "the set of all characters **not** contained within the brackets", and the `+` means 1 or more repeats of the characters before it. The `$` "anchors" at the end of the string, to keep it from eating _any_ `:[^:]+` found within the arn, which would be a ton of them. A little searching for "regex syntax" would have gone a long way, you know

Comment: Thanks Matthew for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Hey Matthew i tried the above regex which you given, it is removing the dev-hello-world. The function name. I checked online, the regex expression is correct. It removes the version number. Is there any help you can do with this thing when running  ansible playbook?

The above jquery spits the below output.

 "populate_arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:12345678:function"

Comment: if that's true, then `Hello-World | json_query('results[0].configuration.function_arn')` clearly does _not_ always contain the version number. If you are certain the versions are always numeric, you can change the `_replace` to be `:[0-9]+$`